# Mysql collation utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci not really case insentive for Cyrillic

Tags: php, mysql, cyrillic, amazon-aurora

I have a table `comments` with collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` containing a column `data` in `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` as well.

Data contained in the `data` field can be in any language, including Russian in Cyrillic.

It appears that `SELECT` `LIKE` queries ran with Cyrillic characters are not case insensitive as they are supposed to be. If an uppercase string is passed, the query fails to match the string.

Please see example below:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE data LIKE "%САМЫЙЛЕНИВЫЙБЛОГЕР%"
```

`[KO]` Result : NULL

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE data LIKE "%самыйленивыйблогер%"
```

`[OK]` Result: Вы оооочень много спрашиваете про волосы и вот #самыйленивыйблогер на ночь глядя решил накатать пост с ответами

The second string has been obtained simply by `mb_strtolower` the original uppercase in php

Is it possible that utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci is not case insensitive for Cyrillic characters?

Comment: By the way when I run `SELECT 'Вы оооочень много спрашиваете про волосы и вот #самыйленивыйблогер на ночь глядя решил накатать пост с ответами' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci 
LIKE '%САМЫЙЛЕНИВЫЙБЛОГЕР%';` I get 1 back so maybe check if the actual column value is in the correct collation.

Comment: SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM database LIKE "comments"

says collation "utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci"

And Phpmyadmin reports the same for the table and the column

Is there another way to double check?

Could this be related to the fact that the table is partitioned?

Comment: Not sure if partitioning affects. Try running that query on your actual DB and see what you get back. Also, the aurora tag seems wrong.

Comment: Yes, the query you suggested returns 1 to me as well. 

I think the Aurora tag is correct, I am running my Mysql server on AWS Aurora